# discord.py | Json file keeps resetting

Tags: json, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord, json
from discord.ext import commands

with open('settings.json', 'r') as f:
    settings = json.load(f)

settings['prefix'] = '!'

with open('settings.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(settings, f, indent=4)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

So here I have a code where when I start the bot, it adds `'prefix': '!'` which works perfectly fine, but the problem is, that once I change the prefix from `!` to something else and re-run the bot, it resets the prefix back to `!`. I have tried many things so far but I still have this issue.

**TL;DR**

I can't figure out how to make the bot save the current prefix so it won't reset back to `!` once I re-run the bot. Please help!

Comment: Please include the code (including the scope) where you are changing the the prefix key

Comment: that is the entire code, but if you also want to see what it looks like inside the json file then here it is

{
    "prefix": "!"
}

Comment: also right now I am only trying to make it save the value without resetting it, once that works I will then make it so it will be the prefix of the bot.

Comment: I was referring to this part "but the problem is, that once I change the prefix from ! to something else "
How are you changing the prefix?

Comment: I am going into the json file and changing it from there.

Comment: Okay, if I understand how this bot should work. One the first run, it should create a key called prefix with a value of '!" and save the json. Then you (manually or with some other process) change the prefix to some other value, ex: 'v'. but when you rerun the bot it resets the prefix in json to '!'. 
You only want the prefix to be '!' if there is no prefix in your json file. 
Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226315/discussion-between-harsha-and-mythcraftmc).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it resets to `!` when you rerun the bot, is that the code starts reading from the first line and will eventually reach this part:

```py
# This will always be executed whenever bot resets
# and will end up setting your prefix to !
with open('settings.json', 'r') as f:
    settings = json.load(f)
settings['prefix'] = '!'
with open('settings.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(settings, f, indent=4)
```

To have variable prefix and a command to change the prefix:

```py
settings_path = 'settings.json' # path to your json file

def get_prefix(client, message): # define get_prefix
    with open(settings_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        settings = json.load(f)
        return settings['prefix'] # Receive the prefix from your settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=(get_prefix))

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # Only allow server admins to change
async def change_prefix(ctx, prefix:str='!'): # If you don't add any prefix, it will use !
    with open(settings_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        settings = json.load(f)
        return settings

    settings['prefix'] = prefix

    with open(settings_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(settings, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f"Prefix changed to {prefix}")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use write mode:

```
with open("file.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

it will reset when you are opening, so you need to open the json file in append mode:

```
with open("file.json", 'a') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

this will avoid the json file from resetting.
another way of doing this is:

```
data = {}

def save():
    with open("file.json", 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    with open("file.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: I tried to append it for json.dump but now every time I stop the bot and run it again, sure it keeps the previose data but ends up adding a new {} with the data which messes up the entire json file.